# How to update the app version in react native ios app?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, react-native-ios

How can I change the apple app version which is build using react native.

I got this email from apple app store -

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "APP_NAME" 1.0 (1.0.2). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90062: This bundle is invalid - The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.1]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Open your app in Xcode by going to ios directory in your project
  either there is `.xcworkspace` double click that or `.xcodeproj`
  double click that.
- Now follow image steps click on 1 then 2 and 3 is where you will change it.
  [image]

Answer (score 12):

Go To *info.plist*, find `CFBundleShortVersionString`, set its `<string>` value with your expected value:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>. 
<string>1.0.0</string>
```

Comment: Might want to update `CFBundleVersion` while you're in there too

Answer (score 0):

navigate to your project then iOS folder open your project  name.xcworkspace like that and change build number or version number

[image]