# Getting incorrect iOS app version number?

Tags: ios, react-native, version

I have a React-Native app project and I am trying to get the app version number as to perform some logic with it, however I seem to be getting a return of `1` when I can see through Xcode that the version is on `5.x.x`...

Since I am developing in a non-xcode IDE I double checked the app version within xcode itself by following the steps in **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998426/3061047)** and you can see by my screenshot below that I am indeed on version `5.x.x`

Following the SO question's instructions I looked in `TARGETS > my_project > General > Identity` and found

[image]

*I also have a test build deployed via appcenter to my phone with a version of `5.2.0`, however this is on Android so could be something or nothing.*

In my RN code I am using [`react-native-version-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-version-check) to get the actual version number

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getVersion = async () => {
        const version = await VersionCheck.getCurrentVersion({platform: 'ios'});
        const build = await VersionCheck.getCurrentBuildNumber();
        console.log({version, build});
        return version;
    }

    getVersion();
}, []);
```

The console logs as a result of this:

```
{"build": "1", "version": "1.0"}
```

Is there something I am missing?

I have also attempted using `DeviceInfo.getVersion()` which again gets me `1.0`...

So either the app version is really `1.0` and Xcode is showing the wrong number, or something is going wrong?